# Underscore (_) not working in headers name Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, laravel-5.3, lumen

We've using some headers for authentication in our API

Request:

```
URL: http://lapi.domain.in/test

Header: {AUTH_TOKEN :NUBibTM0QHJkMzM5}
```

But trying to get header AUTH_TOKEN , its return nothing.

```
$auth_token = $request->header('AUTH_TOKEN');
```

> Note: other headers working fine and when its name has been changed
>   too AUTH-TOKEN then its working.

Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6

Thanks

Comment: I don't think information presented here sufficient to take any decision. SO the stack-overflow court dismiss this question

Comment: Can you see it in the browsers Network panel?

Comment: Problem with AUTH_TOKEN  key when change it to TOKEN then its working

Comment: Check if the header is being passed thru your httpd by writing `var_dump(getallheaders()); die;` as the first statement of your `index.php`. If it is, than grep the source (including vendors) if any middleware uses it.

Comment: Its working other systems of colleagues

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to Apache and not Laravel;
There was a similar issue with Authorization headers in previous versions which was solved by allowing the Authorization headers through htaccess to fix it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Thanks but AUTH_TOKEN key name changed it to TOKEN then its working